# Sensibility in my game using setInterval is not working (js)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So I am creating a game where if someone clicks on parameter icon, it opens a panel with a ranger slide (values: 1 = low sensibility, 2 = medium sensibility, 3 = high sensibility). This ranger slide determines the speed in which my spaceship is moving(sensibility). However I encounter an issue when changing sensibility. My code is having some weird behaviors (sometimes it works sometimes not) Any idea why?
Here is the code:

Ranger slide:

```
<input type="range" id="sensibilty" min="1" max="3" value="2">
```

Js code

```
const loop = function() {
if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {pos.left -= 10} //THIS IS HOW SPACESHIP MOVES WITH KEYBOARD KEYS
if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {pos.left += 10}
if (keys[38] || keys[80]) {pos.top -= 1}
if (keys[40] || keys[75]) {pos.top += 1}}
let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40) //INITIAL SENSIBILITY

function validateSens() {
let sensibilty = document.getElementById("sensibilty").value
if (sensibilty == 1 || sensibilty == "1") {clearInterval(sens); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30)} 
//DIFFERENT SENSIBILITY BASED ON RANGER SLIDE VALUE
if (sensibilty == 2 || sensibilty == "2") {clearInterval(sens); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40)}
//DIFFERENT SENSIBILITY BASED ON RANGER SLIDE VALUE
if (sensibilty == 3 || sensibilty == "3") {clearInterval(sens); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60)}
//DIFFERENT SENSIBILITY BASED ON RANGER SLIDE VALUE
else {alert("Sorry, a bug occured")}} //That gives me an alert if bug occurres
```

Furthermore, this alert sometimes opens, sometimes not... very weird

Comment: Note that `let sens = setInterval(...)` is creating a new interval at every loop. Within the first one second you will end up with 33554432 setInterval loops running in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reassigning the `setInterval()` result.

Check the code below (i also simplified it a bit).

```
function validateSens() {
    clearInterval(sens);
    let sensibilty = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sensibilty").value);

    switch(sensibilty) {
        case 1:
            sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30);
            break;
            
        case 2:
            sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40);
            break;
            
        case 3:
            sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);
            break;
            
        default:
            alert("Sorry, a bug occured");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but very strangely, the alert: "sorry a bug occurred" is always active....

Comment: add a `console.log(sensibility)` and see what value it has (and why it is falling into default switch case)

Comment: Thanks! It now works perfectly with switch command!